# add new rules in sonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner, sonarlint, sonarqube5.1

[image][image]I want to add new rule in sonarQube, so when I enter with an administrator profile I can’t find this button. 
My sonar version is  sonarqube-Community-7.6.
User : admin
Password : admin
And the URL is : http://localhost:9000/coding_rules
There is some screenshots [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ox2SA.png).

Comment: Do you need to write a whole new rule (see [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Writing+Custom+Java+Rules+101)) or only add a existing rule to a quality profile?

Answer (score 0):

You can add rule but you have to create quality profile first.

see the link here ... how to create rule. https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/user-guide/rules/

[image]

Comment: see the link here ... how to create rule. https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/user-guide/rules/